# Kendo Ui MVVM Validation for controls

Tags: html, validation, mvvm, kendo-mvvm

I have tried to apply the `required` attribute in ym HTML for validation. I implemented the logic of MVVM in my screen,

I invoked `validator.validate()` as well, and it's working fine, but I am not getting the notification for the same near my control.

```
  <input class="input-block-level" type="text" id="txtSupplierName" data-bind="value: SupplierName" 
                    placeholder="Supplier Name" required  validationMessage="Supplier Name required {0}"/>
```

validator

```
 validator = $("#supplierForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

Currently I'm handling it with `validator.validate()`
if true go ahead, if false then stop and show alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a span after the input. Use the 'data-for' attribute, and pass it the name of your input control (also, add a name to your input control).

```
<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="txtSupplierName"></span>
```

The CSS class is a Kendo class, so use your own styling if not using Kendo templates.

Answer (score 2):

You try with data-required-msg:

```
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" id="txtSupplierName" data-bind="value:    SupplierName" 
                placeholder="Supplier Name" required  data-bind="attr:{data-required-msg:message}"/>
```

JS:

```
kendo.observable({
message:"Supplier Name required"
});
```